# Hystrix-javanica Dynamically Setting Properties at Class Level

Tags: java, dynamic, properties, hystrix

I am using Hystrix-javanica in a Spring controlled environment. To facilitate parameter configuration at runtime, I annotate the method with `@HystrixCommand` and set the Hystrix command properties dynamically in a different `@PostConstruct` annotated method.

When my class has one method (say methodA) annotated with `@HystrixCommand`, I can set a property at 'command key' level by executing:

```
ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty("hystrix.command.methodA.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", timeout);
```

If I have two or more methods in my class that are annotated with `@HystrixCommand`, instead of setting the properties for each method separately, how can I set them at the class level (or 'group key' level)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can Configure using @DefaultProperties annotation at the class (type) level which allows to default commands properties such as groupKey, threadPoolKey, commandProperties, threadPoolProperties and ignoreExceptions. As

```
@DefaultProperties(groupKey = "TestGroupKey", commandProperties = {
        @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "25000")
}, threadPoolProperties = {
        @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize", value = "50")
})
```